# При скролле подключаем скрипт?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Приветствую!
Попробовал при скролле подключить скрипт

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
  $('.test').after().html('<script type="text/javascript" src="//vk.com/js/api/openapi.js?150"></script> <div id="vk_community_messages"></div><script type="text/javascript"> VK.Widgets.CommunityMessages("vk_community_messages", 127607773, {expanded: "1",tooltipButtonText: "Есть вопрос?"});</script>');
}
```

но ничего не получилось не работает почему то, и не могу понять почему. 
Помогите разобраться в чем проблема.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скрипт `openapi.js` я бы подключал в документе изначально, но даже если динамически, то это лучше делать с помощью метода `$.getScript()` или `$.ajax()` с соответствующим значением параметра `dataType`. Во-вторых, необходимо экранировать кавычки, слеши в исполняемом коде, который вы добавляете на страницу. И в-третьих, при каждом событии `scroll` (*если обработчик у вас вообще установлен*) и верном условии `scrollTop > 0`, будет опять выполняться подключение API и вывод на страницу кода виджета. Поэтому, этот момент тоже я бы отслеживал:

```
var getApi = true;
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0 && getApi) {
    getApi = false;
    $.getScript('//vk.com/js/api/openapi.js?150', function() {
      $('.test').after().html('<div id="vk_community_messages">OOO</div><script type="text/javascript"> VK.Widgets.CommunityMessages(\"vk_community_messages\", 127607773, {expanded: \"1\",tooltipButtonText: \"Есть вопрос?\"});<\/script>');
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Да то что надо спасибо

Comment: или $.ajax() = Просто интересно где можно посмотреть как подключают через ajax. Есть примеры ? Можно ссылка ?.

Comment: @Карен, это обычный [метод jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), просто указывается, как тип ожидаемых данных в ответе - `dataType: 'script'`.

Comment: а проверка на скролл как добавить там ?

Comment: @Карен, похоже, что вы меня не поняли. Метод `$.getScript()` - это укороченная версия метода `$.ajax()` с `dataType: 'script'` Проверка на скролл и прочее, сюда ни коем образом не относятся.